# How to run a Groovy script from a Gradle task in another java process?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

Let's say you have a Groovy script that ends with a `System.exit(...)` call and you want this Groovy script to be executed in a Gradle task. As the `System.exit` call will terminate the whole JVM you want to run this script in another Java process (as using `GroovyShell` does not seem to be an option because to of the `System.exit` call). How can you do this without using a separate Groovy installation's `groovy` command)?

If something like this might work, how do I have to replace `???` and `????`?

```
  javaexec {
    classpath = ???
    mainClass = ????
    args = ['my-script.groovy']
  }
```

---

[Edit] Okay, here's a "minimal reproducible example" as mentioned in the comment below, if that makes the question better understandable:

The Groovy script:

```
    // file: my-script.groovy

    println 'Hello World'
    System.exit(0)
```

The Gradle task (this might be completely wrong and I do not know how to replace the question marks):

```
task runMyScript(type: JavaExec) {
  classpath = ???
  mainClass = ????
  args = ['my-script.groovy']
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you didn't provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how to run groovy script using java command line you can check in groovy shells/batches:

https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/bin/groovy.bat#L30

```
java -cp "$GROOVY_HOME/lib" groovy.ui.GroovyMain myscript.groovy
```

the only question find out gradle/lib folder where usually groovy-all is located

i can suggest this as straight forward:

```
def groovyJar = new File(groovy.ui.GroovyMain.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()?.getLocation()?.toURI())
```

---

Or when using `javaexec` as mentioned above, it's:

```
  javaexec {
    classpath = files(groovy.ui.GroovyMain.protectionDomain.codeSource.location)
    mainClass = 'groovy.ui.GroovyMain'
    args = ['my-script.groovy']
  }
```

Comment: Hmmm, actually this is not working 100%. In my case it uses `groovy-3.0.10.jar` in the classpath so most Groovy stuff is working, but not everything. For example it also needs `groovy-nio-3.0.10.jar` for the extension methods of `java.nio.file.Path` .. and there are also some other additional `groovy-...-3.0.10.jar` files...

Comment: You can include to classpath whole lib directory

Answer (score 0):

An alterntive solution seems to be:

Add the following to `build.gradle`:

```
configurations {
  groovyScript
}

dependencies {
  groovyScript localGroovy()
  ...
}
```

Then later use:

```
  javaexec {
    classpath = configurations.groovyScript
    mainClass = 'groovy.ui.GroovyMain'
    args = ['my-script.groovy']
  }
```

I've just read this somewhere in the web. I do not really understand what this is exactly doing. If someone could explain, that would be great. TYVMIA